# How to compute $\int x(2x-3)\,dx$

Tags: integration

I've recently been doing calculus and I am quite confused on how to integrate.

I was wondering if someone could show me how to determine $\int x(2x-3)\,dx$.

Comment: $2(2x - 3) = 2x^2 - 3x$. Now ... what's the integral of $2x^2$? What's the integral of $-3x$?

Comment: It is easier to separate the expression as a sum.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int x(2x-3) \, dx$$
$$=\int (2x^2 - 3x) \, dx$$
$$=\int 2x^2\, dx - \int 3x \, dx$$
$$=\frac23x^3 - \frac32x^2 + C$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $x(2x-3)=2x^2-3x$ and $\int2x^2-3xdx=\int2x^2dx-\int3xdx=2x^3/3-3x^2/2+C$

Answer (score 1):

There's no one-size-fits-all method to integration (unless you count something like [the Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm)); you just have to become familiar with the patterns and tricks to know when to use what technique. In this case, it's a matter of distributing and then remembering the fact that $\int x^n\ dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$. If you Google "integration techniques" you will find an abundance of resources.